# WCF service has a return type, but clients sees another

Tags: c#, wcf, return

mi wcf service has a function called Richiedicarta, it returns a List, but when i implement it in my client, it says that it cannot implicitely convert type string in type system.collections.generics.List.
Here's the WCF function code

```
public List<string> richiedicarta(int utilcode)
    {
        List<string> card = new List<string>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        switch (utilcode)
        {
            case 0:
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    int indice = rand.Next(0, max-1);
                    card.Add(carta[indice]);
                    carta.Remove(carta[indice]);
                    max--;
                    return card;
                }
                break; //prima mano
            case 1: briscola = carta[rand.Next(0, max-1)]; card.Add(briscola); max--; break; //briscola
            case 2: if (carta.Count == 0) { card.Add(briscola); } else { card.Add(carta[rand.Next(0, max-1)]); } max--; break; //nuova mano
        }
        return card;
    }
```

and here's the client function code

```
static List<String> ricevicarte(int param)
    {

        List<string> carte = cl.richiedicarta(param); // here it gives that error

        List<String> cards = null;
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            if(carte[i]==" ")
            {
                carte[i] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                cards.Add(carte[i]);
            }
        }
        return cards;
    }
```

cl is my ServiceClient instance

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: What is the client's WCF proxy contract looking like? It appears like it's a contract mismatch.

Comment: cannot implicitely convert type string in type system.collections.generics.List<string>.
sorry, i wrote the question in a bad way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your **`service reference`**.Make sure to uncheck the Reuse types in referenced assemblies checkbox and put address of your new service in Address textbox.

Comment: i did it, and it has worked, but now the return type is "BriscolaService.richiedicartaResponse", and it won't accept my parameter because "impossible to convert int to briscolaWCFdef_Client.BriscolaService.richiedicartaRequest"

Comment: you need to create a object of that type and assign the property and then pass

Comment: i found out i checked "always generate message contracts", without it it doesn't require that kind of object, but return tipe of my WCF function has changed from string to string[], problem still remains

Comment: it is written in the question